# Attempt to write vlookup output (within for loop) to next blank cell in range results in gaps due to non-blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

this is my first post so please bear with me. I've had a look around for a solution but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I have a vba module which aims to do the following (relevant code at the bottom of the post):

- lookup each value in Column 1 of Range A, Worksheet 1 against values in Column 1 of Range B, Worksheet 2
- if a match is found, copy the corresponding value in Column 3 of Range B in Worksheet 2 to the next empty cell in Output Range in Worksheet 3.

The vlookup part of this works fine, but I am having trouble outputting to the next blank row of the output range. It appears that the cells which appear blank are actually not blank. I checked this on the worksheet using the function =code(cellwhichlooksblank), which returned 32. I know I can get around this outside of VBA by referring to cells which = "" instead of using Blanks as a cell type, but I don't know how to implement this within my VBA. Any help would be appreciated. I've copied the relevant parts of the code below (I haven't provided all the definitions etc as I didn't think them relevant).

```
ISMcount = Sheets("ISMVer").Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In Sheets("Verification").Range("B2:B" & lr)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, lookupWS.Range("B3:D" & counter), 3, False) > 0 Then:
        Sheets("ISMVer").Range("B" & ISMcount).Value = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, lookupWS.Range("B3:D" & counter), 3, False)
        ISMcount = Sheets("ISMVer").Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
    Next cell
```

Comment: This is never a good idea: if you're new to vba, it's best if you dont use it: "On Error Resume Next", it will just hide the (useful) error messages

Comment: Thanks Tom, I've removed the line from my code. I'm not actually getting any error however.

Comment: If `=Code(cellwhichlooksblank)` is returning 32, then it's got a space character in it.  You could try adding a line to replace all cells containing a space with a null string, (i.e. `Range.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", Lookat:=XlWhole`) before running the rest of your code.  You may find that you also have to save the workbook after running the replace in order for XL to detect these cells as actually being blank.

Comment: @blackworx - thanks for the input; I tried as you suggested (replacing range with my output range), including the save, and XL somehow still considers the cells nonblank?!

Comment: You're welcome.  Likely it was multiple spaces (e.g. `=CODE(A1)` would return 32 regardless of how many spaces there were in cell A1). Was going to comment again as I figured this was a distinct possibility but got sidetracked and I see you have solved your problem now anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` finds an empty cell in a contiguous block of cells. It will fail if there are no blank cells in the range

`Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row`

This is the most popular pattern to return the next empty cell in a list

`Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

[image]

### UPDATE

This will find the first empty cell in column B after B1

> Range("B:B").Find(What:="*",After:=Range("B1"), SearchDirection:=xlNext)

---

Remove `On Error Resume Next`. Create a variable to hold the VLookup's value and set a breakpoint.  Run the code and check the value of the variable under different scenarios.

[image]

```
For Each cell In Sheets("Verification").Range("B2:B" & lr)
    Value = Application.VLookup(cell, lookupWS.Range("B3:D" & Counter), 3, False)

    If Value Then
        With Sheets("ISMVer").Range("B:B").Find(What:="*", After:=Range("B1"), SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            .Value = Application.VLookup(cell, lookupWS.Range("B3:D" & Counter), 3, False)
        End With
    End If

Next cell
```

Comment: Hello Thomas - thanks but my output range could also have manual input by users so I'd prefer to use the first blank cell in the range rather than going to the end of the list i.e. there may be gaps which need filling.

Comment: @ Thomas-Inzina - thanks for your update, it has helped me to realise where my newbie error has occurred. My vlookup is finding matches in the first column, then copying the 3rd column of the lookup table. However, sometimes the 3rd column is blank. I thought that using IF Vlookup > 0 within the loop would mean these entries were skipped, but instead a space the size of one character is copied - hence the nonblank issue. How can I avoid this and only copy the cells which contain data? Nest another IF within the loop?

Comment: apologies -  I pressed enter by accident and only sent the first part of my reply - it turns out that the strange behavior was due to my mistake after all, as described above. Working on fixing it just now, any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: @liam391 I added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience - i was able to use your code example to solve my problem (the cells that I want to copy will always be numbers, so I used: If IsNumeric(value) Then with Sheets("ISMVer").... etc)

Comment: @liam391 Thanks for accepting my answer.  Happy coding :)